# Randonmly access denied error occured while accessing pages HDIV

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, hdiv

I am facing issue of access denied **randomly** for any secure request. Access denied page is nothing but error page will appeared HDIV exception occures. The trouble part is that we have configured log for HDIV but we haven't getting any exception. When the same page refreshed then page loaded correctly.
we have following application configuration and environmentJBoss 5 and spring mvc security 2.5 and HDIV version 1.1.

In Log now we are geting eeror message **INVALID_HDIV_PARAMETER_VALUE** But not much details

I am not able to identify what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

INVALID_HDIV_PARAMETER_VALUE means the request does not contains the HDIV_STATE parameter. If this happens once in a while then you are submiting the form before it completly loaded. I faced the same problem i solved it by placing a div with higher z-index the using jQuery fadeout the div on document ready